# Which platforms don't use string comparison in type_info op==?

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid, typeinfo

Here is a typical implementation of `type_info::operator==`:

```
#if _PLATFORM_SUPPORTS_UNIQUE_TYPEINFO
    bool operator==(const type_info& __rhs) const {
      return __mangled_name == __rhs.__mangled_name;
    }
#else
    bool operator==(const type_info& __rhs) const {
      return __mangled_name == __rhs.__mangled_name ||
             strcmp(__mangled_name, __rhs.__mangled_name) == 0;
    }
#endif
```

In libstdc++ it's controlled with `__GXX_MERGED_TYPEINFO_NAMES`,
in libc++ it's `_LIBCPP_NONUNIQUE_RTTI_BIT`,
MSVC always compares strings.

What are the platforms which don't compare strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In libstdc++ it's controlled with `__GXX_MERGED_TYPEINFO_NAMES`

[In newer versions of gcc (since 23 Jul 2009) this macro is set to 0 by default](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/62164d4c3690257a01326783bed77c15831d52b9). It always compares pointers first and if that fails they do the full string comparison. [See here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/typeinfo#L48):

> We used to do inline pointer comparison by default if weak symbols are available, but even with weak symbols sometimes names are not merged when objects are loaded with `RTLD_LOCAL`, so now we always use `strcmp` by default.

Comment: Notably, it's *possible* for a target to override this, but no target actually does.

Comment: @o11c 3 targets do override it: `__GXX_MERGED_TYPEINFO_NAMES=0`.

Comment: Er, right, but they overwrite it to the value it already has.