# When does GCC give different typeids in different DSOs?

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, linkage, typeid

Using the same version of GCC/Clang, is there a way to ensure `typeid` gives different results for the same type in two different DSOs, such that `dynamic_cast` and/or `catch`ing an exception across a DSO boundary will fail?

Frustratingly, I have seen the case where an exception wasn't caught when thrown across a DSO boundary, and I had to add  `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to the exception class to make it work. But I can't remember where or in what circumstance. And now I can't reproduce it in a toy example!

I've been trying to come up with an example with two linked libraries (or library and executable), both compiled  with `-fvisibility=hidden`, and both `#include`ing the same header defining some inline polymorphic (`virtual`) classes.

But for the life of me, tooling around in Compiler Explorer, I can't seem to break it. The `type_info` seems to evaluate the same (e.g. has the same `.hash_code()`) in both DSOs, and accordingly `dynamic_cast`s and `catch`ing exceptions work across DSOs.

Can anyone give some hint as to what circumstances this will actually fail?

Comment: It will fail on android.

Comment: Messy Compiler Explorer experimentation here: https://godbolt.org/z/orGrxjojs

Comment: Maybe it was for older gcc versions? Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49773686/3740047 and also see [this comment](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/9693459e030977d6e906ea7eb587ed09ee4fddbd/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/typeinfo#L51C13-L51C13).